# Place custom argument matcher on mock called multiple times

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, python-unittest

Let's say I have the following code snippet:

```
# foo.py
class FooClass:
  def foo(req: ComplexRequestObject) -> resp:
    ...

# bar.py
def bar(f: FooClass, ...):
  # gen req_1 and req_2 somehow
  resp_1 = f.foo(req_1)
  resp_2 = f.foo(req_2)
  ...
```

I want to write a unittest on bar mocking out foo, and place expectations on the arguments. Here is what I tried

```
def partially_equals(self: ComplexRequestObject, other: ComplexRequestObject):
    return self.property_1 == other.property_1


class Matcher(object):
    def __init__(self, compare, some_obj):
        self.compare = compare
        self.some_obj = some_obj

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.compare(self.some_obj, other)

# Now in the test itself

  def test_thing_1(self):
      # call bar
      bar(mock_foo_class, ...)
      mock_foo_class.foo.assert_has_calls(
          call(Matcher(partially_equals, ComplexRequestObject(property_1="hello"))),
          call(Matcher(partially_equals, ComplexRequestObject(property_1="hello"))),
      )
```

When I run this, it keeps telling me that `'foo' does not contain all of ('', ({'property_1': 'hello'},), {}) in its call list, found ...`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo

```
def test_thing_1(self):
    # call bar
    bar(mock_foo_class, ...)
    mock_foo_class.foo.assert_has_calls(
        call(Matcher(partially_equals, ComplexRequestObject(property_1="hello"))),
        call(Matcher(partially_equals, ComplexRequestObject(property_1="hello"))),
    )
```

Should be

```
def test_thing_1(self):
    # call bar
    bar(mock_foo_class, ...)
    mock_foo_class.foo.assert_has_calls(
        [
            call(Matcher(partially_equals, ComplexRequestObject(property_1="hello"))),
            call(Matcher(partially_equals, ComplexRequestObject(property_1="hello")))
        ]
    )
```

(Basically the calls needed to be passed in as a list)